# Spark Dataset API - join

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

I am trying to use the Spark [Dataset](https://databricks.com/blog/2016/01/04/introducing-spark-datasets.html) API but I am having some issues doing a simple join.

Let's say I have two dataset with fields: `date | value`, then in the case of `DataFrame` my join would look like:

```
val dfA : DataFrame
val dfB : DataFrame

dfA.join(dfB, dfB("date") === dfA("date") )
```

However for `Dataset` there is the `.joinWith` method, but the same approach does not work:

```
val dfA : Dataset
val dfB : Dataset

dfA.joinWith(dfB, ? )
```

What is the argument required by `.joinWith` ?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

To use `joinWith` you first have to create a `DataSet`, and most likely two of them. To create a `DataSet`, you need to create a case class that matches your schema and call `DataFrame.as[T]` where `T` is your case class. So:

```
case class KeyValue(key: Int, value: String)
val df = Seq((1,"asdf"),(2,"34234")).toDF("key", "value")
val ds = df.as[KeyValue]
// org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[KeyValue] = [key: int, value: string]
```

You could also skip the case class and use a tuple:

```
val tupDs = df.as[(Int,String)]
// org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[(Int, String)] = [_1: int, _2: string]
```

Then if you had another case class / DF, like this say:

```
case class Nums(key: Int, num1: Double, num2: Long)
val df2 = Seq((1,7.7,101L),(2,1.2,10L)).toDF("key","num1","num2")
val ds2 = df2.as[Nums]
// org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[Nums] = [key: int, num1: double, num2: bigint]
```

Then, while the syntax of `join` and `joinWith` are similar, the results are different:

```
df.join(df2, df.col("key") === df2.col("key")).show
// +---+-----+---+----+----+
// |key|value|key|num1|num2|
// +---+-----+---+----+----+
// |  1| asdf|  1| 7.7| 101|
// |  2|34234|  2| 1.2|  10|
// +---+-----+---+----+----+

ds.joinWith(ds2, df.col("key") === df2.col("key")).show
// +---------+-----------+
// |       _1|         _2|
// +---------+-----------+
// | [1,asdf]|[1,7.7,101]|
// |[2,34234]| [2,1.2,10]|
// +---------+-----------+
```

As you can see, `joinWith` leaves the objects intact as parts of a tuple, while `join` flattens out the columns into a single namespace. (Which will cause problems in the above case because the column name "key" is repeated.)

Curiously enough, I have to use `df.col("key")` and `df2.col("key")` to create the conditions for joining `ds` and `ds2` -- if you use just `col("key")` on either side it does not work, and `ds.col(...)` doesn't exist. Using the original `df.col("key")` does the trick, however.

Comment: detailed explanation. Just one confusion. Is there a better way to write typed join condition. for e.g. df.col("key") can we have something more type safe that can resolve correctness of "key" at compile time.

Comment: I completely agree, based on this syntax there is no use in creating the Dataset, so where is the benefit? I can't get over the fact that there is no typed alternative.. Such a pity!

Comment: there is a workaround in this [answer of "Perform a typed join in Scala with Spark Datasets"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40605167/perform-a-typed-join-in-scala-with-spark-datasets?rq=1)

Answer (score 9):

From https://docs.cloud.databricks.com/docs/latest/databricks_guide/05%20Spark/1%20Intro%20Datasets.html

it looks like you could just do

```
dfA.as("A").joinWith(dfB.as("B"), $"A.date" === $"B.date" )
```

Answer (score 2):

For the above example, you can try the below:

Define a case class for your output

```
case class JoinOutput(key:Int, value:String, num1:Double, num2:Long)
```

Join two Datasets with `Seq("key")`, this will help you to avoid two duplicate key columns in the output, which will also help to apply the case class or fetch the data in the next step

```
val joined = ds.join(ds2, Seq("key")).as[JoinOutput]
// res27: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[JoinOutput] = [key: int, value: string ... 2 more fields]
```

The result will be flat instead:

```
joined.show

+---+-----+----+----+
|key|value|num1|num2|
+---+-----+----+----+
|  1| asdf| 7.7| 101|
|  2|34234| 1.2|  10|
+---+-----+----+----+
```

Comment: you don't specifically answer the question, but the Seq("key") tip helped me out

Comment: You are not answering how to use `.joinWith`, and also `.join` is actually an untyped transformation, in which case you are not benefitting from the type safety of `Dataset`