# Typesafe Joins with Spark Datasets Less Safe Than I'd Expect

Tags: scala, apache-spark

In trying to make this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40673973/424173) to [Perform a typed join in Scala with Spark Datasets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40605167/perform-a-typed-join-in-scala-with-spark-datasets]) available as an implicit, I've run across something I don't understand.

In the test below, the signature of `innerJoin` is  `def innerJoin[U, K](ds2: Dataset[U])(f: T => K, g: U => K)(implicit e1: Encoder[(K, T)], e2: Encoder[(K, U)], e3: Encoder[(T, U)])`, but I call it with `f: Foo => String` and `g: Bar => Int`. I would expect an error at compile time, but it compiles just fine. Why is that?

What actually happens is it compiles just fine and the test fails with `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.Any` when Spark tries to create a product encoder (for the resulting `((K, Foo),(K, Bar))` tuples, I think). I assume the `Any` appears as the common "parent" of `Int` and `String`.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.{Dataset, Encoder, SparkSession}
import org.scalatest.Matchers
import org.scalatest.testng.TestNGSuite
import org.testng.annotations.Test

case class Foo(a: String)

case class Bar(b: Int)

class JoinTest extends TestNGSuite with Matchers {
  import JoinTest._

  @Test
  def testJoin(): Unit = {
    val spark = SparkSession.builder()
      .master("local")
      .appName("test").getOrCreate()

    import spark.implicits._

    val ds1 = spark.createDataset(Seq(Foo("a")))
    val ds2 = spark.createDataset(Seq(Bar(123)))

    val jd = ds1.innerJoin(ds2)(_.a, _.b)

    jd.count shouldBe 0
  }
 }

object JoinTest {
  implicit class Joins[T](ds1: Dataset[T]) {
    def innerJoin[U, K](ds2: Dataset[U])(f: T => K, g: U => K)
     (implicit e1: Encoder[(K, T)], e2: Encoder[(K, U)], e3: Encoder[(T, U)]): Dataset[(T, U)] = 
     {
       val ds1_ = ds1.map(x => (f(x), x))
       val ds2_ = ds2.map(x => (g(x), x))
       ds1_.joinWith(ds2_, ds1_("_1") === ds2_("_1")).map(x => (x._1._2, x._2._2))
    }
   }
}
```

Comment: `K` is, in fact, inferred to be `Any`.

Comment: That's sounds like a dependency problem. Could you include build definition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct that `Any` is getting inferred as the common parent of `String` and `Int` and so used as `K`. `Function` is covariant in the output type. So a `Foo => String` is a valid subclass of `Foo => Any`.

The common way to fix this kind of thing is to use two type parameters and an implicit `=:=`. For instance:

```
def innerJoin[U, K1, K2](ds2: Dataset[U])(f: T => K1, g: U => K2)
  (implicit eq: K1 =:= K2, e1: Encoder[(K2, T)], e2: Encoder[(K2, U)], e3: Encoder[(T, U)]): Dataset[(T, U)] = 
  {
    val ds1_ = ds1.map(x => (eq(f(x)), x))
    ... rest the same as before ...
```

Comment: Aha! I keep looking at `=:=`, but didn't think to add another type parameter.