# Type Safe joins in Spark using Java

Tags: java, apache-spark, join, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

I have two datasets and I am joining them as follows using java

```
Dataset<Row> joineddata = ds1.join(ds2, col("col1").equalTo(col("col2")), "inner");
```

Can anyone tell me how to join two Datasets in Apace Spark in a type safe manner using java. I can find examples for type safe join in scala. But I cant find the same using java.

can any one suggest me a link or something related to this

Comment: Could you link the examples you have found and explain why you couldn't apply these in Java?

Comment: @user10465355 example is in this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40605167/perform-a-typed-join-in-scala-with-spark-datasets

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, I don't think you can so far.

scala community has implemented this: https://github.com/typelevel/frameless. but since it's using Cats, it's hard to port it over into Java. and even with this lib, you are not dealing with native Spark anymore, therefore not all Spark APIs are supported in frameless.

as soon as you join 2 datasets, you will get dataframe as a result, therefore losing the type safety. `row.getAs` is basically a type casting, so RT exception is inevitable.